# Alphabetically sort an array in a struct?

Tags: python, sorting, struct

I have a problem with my code when I sort my struct alphabetically in the function of some column

For example I have:

```
name: Bela message: abc priority: 1
name: Carla message: efg priority: 0
name: Ana message: xyz priority: 0
```

And the output needs to be like this:

```
name: Ana message: xyz priority: 0
name: Bela message: abc priority: 1
name: Carla message: efg priority: 0
```

My code is like this:

```
class structura:
    prioritate = 0
    destinatar = ""
    continut = ""
n = input("mesaje maxime: ");
cutie = [structura() for i in range(n)]

for i in range(n):
    print "\nAdaugare mesaj %d" %(i + 1)
    cutie[i].prioritate= input("Prioritate mesaj :")
    cutie[i].destinatar = raw_input("Destinatar mesaj: ")
    cutie[i].continut = raw_input("Continut mesaj: ")

i=0
    while i<n-1:
        if cutie[i].prioritate==0:
            if cutie[i].destinatar>cutie[i+1].destinatar:
                cutie[i].destinatar,cutie[i+1].destinatar=cutie[i+1].destinatar,cutie[i].destinatar
                cutie[i].continut,cutie[i+1].continut=cutie[i+1].continut,cutie[i].continut
                i=0
                print i
            else:
                i+=1
        else:
            i+=1

for i in range(n):
    print "cutie: prioritate= %d | destinatar= %s | continut= %s" %(cutie[i].prioritate, cutie[i].destinatar, cutie[i].continut)
```

But with this sorting code it's doesn't work(it's sort just cutie.destinatar only, instead of cutie.destintar and cutie.continut):

```
i=0
    while i<n-1:
        if cutie[i].prioritate==0:
            if cutie[i].destinatar>cutie[i+1].destinatar:
                cutie[i].destinatar,cutie[i+1].destinatar=cutie[i+1].destinatar,cutie[i].destinatar
                cutie[i].continut,cutie[i+1].continut=cutie[i+1].continut,cutie[i].continut
                i=0
                print i
            else:
                i+=1
        else:
            i+=1
```

I tried with the sorted function too, but it doesn't work with my struct form. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to sort the objects according to an attribute. `sorted` accepts a `key` parameter, which is the value according to which you want to sort.

```
my_sorted_list = sorted(cutie, key = lambda x: x.destinatar)
```

Comment: i tryed but it's doens't sort with my struct class

Comment: `sorted` does not sort the list in-place, it returs a new one. edited the answer

Comment: yes, it's work now, thanks for help, one day in documentation for such a simple solution

Comment: `key=operator.itemgetter('destinatar')` would be faster.